# Problem running ASP.NET MVC 2 website on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET MVC 2 website from VS2010 beta 2 to IIS7. The publish works fine but none of the routes work, so when I go to the URL http://localhost/myapp/Home/Index I get the error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The
>   resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.

I'm deploying to a virtual directory which is using an app pool configured for the .NET 4 framework with managed pipeline mode set to integrated. Also, if I go Basic Settings->Test Connection, both tests pass. From what I understand, it should just work?

I don't have any problems deploying Nerd Dinner from VS2008, that works fine.

Comment: Looks like the same problem that I'm having here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854808

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the right MVC dll in your publish?

When ever I've had problems browsing my MVC applications it's been because I didn't include the MVC dll in the bin folder.

Comment: I just set CopyLocal to true on System.Web.Mvc.dll and it's made no difference. V2 of the MVC dll is in the GAC anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with ASP.NET MVC, **I've seen that a `Default.aspx` page is required for IIS to function correctly**. I'm using the page that was included in the ASP.NET MVC 1 template. Unfortunately, the ASP.NET MVC 2 does not include this page (to the best of my knowledge), so you should add the following to your project:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNamespace._Default" %>

<%-- Please do not delete this file. It is used to ensure that ASP.NET MVC is activated by IIS when a user makes a "/" request to the server. --%>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the current path so that the Routing handler can correctly interpret
            // the request, then restore the original path so that the OutputCache module
            // can correctly process the response (if caching is enabled).

            string originalPath = Request.Path;
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
            IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
            httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
        }
    }
}
```