# The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, cassini, iis-7.5

I have a hybrid asp.net web forms / mvc application that I recently converted to .net 4 with mvc2. I have set-up that application to run on IIS 7.5 (on Windows 7) and the web forms part of the site is running okay but the MVC part is not. Whenever I try and access a page that needs to go through the routing engine I get

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002

I'm debugging this web site through VS2010 (so I've set-it-up to use IIS instead of Cassini) and when I put a break point in the Application_Start function it is never hit so the routes are never registered. When I put a break point in the Page_Load function in one of the aspx page code-behinds it gets hit. So it seems that the problem is that the route is not being registered.

What am I missing?

Comment: This error could also occur if your App Pool's Managed Pipeline mode is set to Classic mode, rather than Integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with ASP.NET MVC, **I've seen that a `Default.aspx` page is required for IIS to function correctly**. I'm using the page that was included in the ASP.NET MVC 1 template. Unfortunately, the ASP.NET MVC 2 does not include this page (to the best of my knowledge), so you should add the following to your project:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNamespace._Default" %>

<%-- Please do not delete this file. It is used to ensure that ASP.NET MVC is activated by IIS when a user makes a "/" request to the server. --%>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the current path so that the Routing handler can correctly interpret
            // the request, then restore the original path so that the OutputCache module
            // can correctly process the response (if caching is enabled).

            string originalPath = Request.Path;
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
            IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
            httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading somewhere about a similar problem that Global.asax events weren't firing. Try to remove the Global.asax file and add it again (just remember to re-add the needed routes code).

Comment: This is not the right resolution against the issue. it just way to refuse issue. what about the production server environment ? If user expecting the Logon page as default and as you routed in the Globle.asax and if still it is not accessing , and we are need hundreds of setting to be run application ... it is just bullsheet...by microsoft that deployment making prolem every time and need R&D after each new pach of IIS .

Answer (score 0):

I had a WebForms, and when I added the API files I needed to change my global.asax file too. All I did was create a new blank API project and then copy the files across. 
When you add the text in the global.asax file, you get told of other libraries you need (such as WebApiConfig). Simply follow the trail.